# Eslint with MDX and vsCode

Tags: eslint

I am currently working with `.mdx` files within vscode and realised that eslint isn't really working the way I am expecting it too.
For example take this file

```
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs';

import { useResponsive, getBreakpoints } from './useResponsive';

<Meta
  title="Hooks/useResponsive"
  component={useResponsive}
  parameters={{ chromatic: { disable: true } }}
/>

# useResponsive
This hook returns true or false depending on if your screen matches the requested breakpoints
```

I have installed [eslint-mdx](https://github.com/mdx-js/eslint-mdx) and I would expect eslint to tell me that `getBreakpoints` isn't being used. It does if I run eslint via the command line, but I am expecting vscode to also add those red squiggly lines telling me the same thing.

Does anyone know of what eslint or vscode settings I might need to use to get something like this to work

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: @Jasard no i havent but I also havn't looked at it much in awhile. Il probably go back to it when I have some free time

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but solved it by enabling the validation for `markdown` and `mdx` in `settings.json` in VScode.

Add this rule to your `settings.json`:

```
"eslint.validate": [
  "markdown",
  "mdx",
  ...
]
```